# How is the rocksDB open function implemented

Tags: rocksdb

I looked into the rocksDB source code but I was unable to find the implementation of the open function for DB. 
Ex: rocksdb::DB::Open(options, "/tmp/testdb", &db);

If I get the source or explanation it would be helpful.

Comment: I think when a negative rating is given by someone they should explain it why. Everyone comes here either to learn or to get their doubts clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of rocksdb's `rocksdb::DB` is spread across multiple sources. It is declared in `include/rocksdb/db.h`, but implemented in multiple files starting with `db_impl` in `db/`. The one you are looking for is `db_impl_open.cc`: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/db/db_impl_open.cc.

Comment: Thank you. If any more doubts we will get back.
Cannot upvote because of low reputation points.